# Ionic - Touch Event for When the Touch Began on a Different Element?

Tags: ionic-framework, hammer.js

I am using Ionic to make a word game where the user can select a series of adjacent letters in a single swipe.  The letters are implemented as individual div elements.

I know what event to use for starting letter (touchstart seems to work well), but I can't figure out what event to use for the middle tiles.  Touchstart doesn't work; touchdrag doesn't seem to work.  In essence, the "mouse" is already down when they begin swiping over that letter in the middle.

Any insights on how I can detect ANY touch (whether it's a start or whether the user is already in the middle of a "swipe" that began on another tile)?

Comment: `touchmove` may work for all cases. That would replace `touchstart` though.

Comment: Oddly, and infuriatingly, these events (including touchmove) always fire on the FIRST element where the "drag" started (even if the swipe has moved on to other elements).  The event target is always the first touched element.

Comment: I have used [elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) previously for things like this to grab each element that was `touchmoved`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) with a `touchmove` event. So inside your `touchmove` callback function, include the `(e)` parameter for the event and try this to gather all elements touched.

```
var touchedIds = [];
var touches = e.originalEvent.touches;

for(var x = 0; x < touches.length; x++) {
    var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[x];
    var element = document.elementFromPoint(touch.clientX, touch.clientY);

    touchedIds[x] = element; // however you want to add it to the array. 
}
```

You end up with an array of elements touched.You may need to filter out the extras to get a distinct array of them, but that would be trivial.